# Datetimepicker bootstrap display in the input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a big problem with my datetimepicker in the template. So my code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    language:  'fr',
    weekStart: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayBtn:  0,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minuteStep: 5,
    forceParse: 1
});
```

When I click on the select box I get the error :

```
TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
```

Normally everything is imported.

```
<input type="text"
               id="{{ form.begin.name }}"
               name="{{ form.begin.name }}"
               value="{{ form.begin.value ? form.begin.value : '' }}"
               placeholder="DГ©but"
               class="form-control datetimepicker"
               data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii"
               {% if form.begin.required %}required="required"{% endif %} />
```

Comment: can you pack your code at the end of the body? or can you pack it in a jquery document.ready function ?

Comment: I tried with document.ready() and an the end of the body but no result

Comment: do u have more then one datapicker on form ?!

Comment: I have 2 datetimepicker on this form

Comment: try to use $('#datetimepickerid')